# Escaping quotes in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a bit of a problem escaping quotes in the following example:

```
var newId = "New Id number for this line";

$(id).html('<td><input type="text" id="my' + newId + '" onKeyUp="runFunction("#my' + newId + '");"></td>');
```

The issue is that when I look at the generated code the id does update to `id="myNewId"`, but in the function call it looks like this:

```
onkeyup="runFunction(" #row2="" );=""
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just don't put JavaScript into the HTML string:

```
$(id).html(
  '<td><input type="text" id="my' + newId + '"></td>'
).find("input").keyup( function() {
  runFunction("#my" + newId);
});
```

Thinking about it, in this special case you can exchange the `keyup()` function body for:

```
  runFunction(this);
```

because you seem to want to run the function on the object itself.

Comment: +1 for the *more jQuery like* approach (you were a bit faster than me ;)).

Comment: It is a great *alternative*, but not an answer to the question.

Comment: @patrick: Sometimes, when it hurts doing something in a certain way, changing your approach is a viable option. ;-)

Comment: I do agree. Just being nit-picky. :o)

Answer (score 6):

You need to use HTML character references for HTML attribute values. Try this:

```
function htmlEncode(str) {
    var map = {"&":"amp", "<":"lt", ">":"gt", '"':"quot", "'":"#39"};
    return str.replace(/[&<>"']/g, function(match) { return "&" + map[match] + ";"; });
}

$(id).html('<td><input type="text" id="my' + newId + '" onKeyUp="' + htmlEncode('runFunction("#my' + newId + '");') + '"></td>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to escape the attribute's quotes.

```
var newId = "New Id number for this line";

$(id).html('<td><input type="text" id="my' + newId + '" onKeyUp="runFunction(\'#my' + newId + '\');"></td>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use escaped single quotes `\'` to surround the `#my...` part.